# How to detect browser focus on mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

The application I'm developing is built around jQuery Mobile and some Ajax to refresh parts of the page.  Like sites that use automatic refresh, I want to stop the refresh after some condition (time/visibility/etc.) so my server isn't bombarded with unneeded requests.  The application has a status screen that is commonly checked by the user, and ideally my scripts would know that the browser window has come into focus and it would be a good time to refresh.  I've done this before in desktop webapps, but I'm noticing a lot of variation on the mobile side between different platforms and browsers, for example:

- window.onfocus() does/n't fire when the browser gains focus
- window.onfocus() does/n't fire when tabs are switched in a browser
- Javascript is/n't suspended between tab switches and/or switches away from browser

The best I've been able to do so far is a set of heuristics that look at available events + when there was detected user interaction with the page, but it's clunky and results in cases where the user jumps back to the page and has to manually refresh.  Not great.

Any clever techniques for solving this?

Comment: An alternate solution might be to check for user input. How about you set the current time in a variable every time the user interacts with the page. This way you can create a rule that only triggers the ajax call if the page has been used for the last minute or two.

Comment: I'm currently doing this. It helps, but there is the common case in my application where the user simply switches to the web page or unlocks his phone to look at the status (no interaction required).

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to know if browser window has been out of focus, use the requestAnimationFrame function.

```
window.requestAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                          <add browsers here>
```

Then in your code

```
var lastupdate = new Date()
(function loop() {
      var now = new Date();

      if ( now - lastupdate > <some treshold like 1 second> ) {
          // browser was suspended and did come back to focus
      }
      lastupdate = now;

      window.requestAnimFrame(loop);
})();
```

Trick is, that browsers do not give animation frame if tab or window is out of focus. Normal setInterval and setTimeouts will still work. This loop will run continously when window is on focus, but overhead is minimal, it's called maybe 3-5 times per second in mobile devices.

Comment: I will take a look at this. My immediate question (with no investigation) would be how widely this is supported.  Thanks.

Comment: This works in IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Android and iOS devices (also in most other mobiles). IT does not work AFAIK in any older browser that does not support HTML5 canvas.

Comment: According this list, it isn't well supported in mobile browsers.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe ... But the post gives a brighter view: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/